# tight tcolorboxes

Tags: tcolorbox, fbox

I want something like a tcolorbox but that it's width and heigth is just as large as its content, I mean that the margin of the box is as tight as possible and the box is centered, is important too that I can enter things like verbatim or lst listings, like I would be able to in a regular tcolorbox

[image]

Comment: Welcome! `\tcbox` does precisely that. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\tcbox{A tight tcolorbox.}
\end{document}`.

Comment: yeah but I can't use verbatim inside that \tcbox{}

Answer (score 3):

`tcolorbox` already has this. You basically need the `hbox` key. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins,listings]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}  


\newtcblisting{mylisting}{% 
listing only,enhanced,drop fuzzy shadow,hbox,
frame style={upper left=blue,upper right=red,lower left=yellow,lower right=green}, 
interior style={left color=blue!30,right color=cyan!30,middle
color=white,shading angle=10}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}
WRITE (*,(2I6,F10.4)) istart,istop,step
\end{mylisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I hadn't thought about \newtcblisting because I was going for verbatim, because with lstlisting the tcolorbox took the width of the page, but I solved that problem by eliminating "\lstset{style=mystyle}", you see I had defined mystyle for other codes, but now when I want to use that style I just add [style=mystyle], so thank you again, you've solved all of my problems